# jquery validate on client not working

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have created a simple form that has two elements, and I am attempting to configure jquery validation so that the elements are verified on a button click. This is a normal button and not a button that is submitted.

I have started this in a blank mvc project in Visual Studio, and I have ensured that I have the following libraries included

```
query.js
jquery-ui.js
jquery.validate.js
bootstrap.css
bootstrap.js
```

The form I have created only has two input controls and a button

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="formtextmatch">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea required id="text" name="text" 
                     class="form-control has-error" rows="5" 
                     placeholder="enter text to search for"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subtext" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subtext</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input required type="text" id="subtext" name="subtext" 
                     class="form-control" value="Polly" 
                     placeholder="enter subtext to search for" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
                <input type="button" id="GetCount" name="GetCount" 
                    value="Get Count" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have the following script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formtextmatch").validate({
            rules: {
                text: "required",
                subtext: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                text: "Text is required",
                subtext: "Subtext is required"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter('.form-group');
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Which I am trying to set up to have the two text boxes as required fields, with error messages to be displayed, and to then set the css to indicate an error with the controls not being valid

Right now I have a very simple script on the button click to validate the form

```
    $("#GetCount").click(function() {
        if (!$("#formtextmatch").valid()) {
            alert('form is invalid');
            return;
        }
    });
```

However when I click the button on the form, the validation does not appear to be executed.

I have hopefully created a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/DarrenGuy/0ttwzgss/

I have tried added the attribute "required" onto the html elements, but that does not appear to work either, I have also change the button click to validate(), but research has said that you should be using valid() and not validate() for a button click

I believe that I have everything set up correctly, but as the validation is not working, I am hoping that I have missed something very simple and basic with the form to get the validation working.

UPDATE :
I have been told that the fiddle works, so the problem must be with something that I have done incorrectly inside my project.

This is the bundles that I have configured

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/blockUI.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toastr").Include(
        "~/Scripts/toastr.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/toastr.css"
                  ));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

and this is the full html for the _Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Test for eviivo</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                     data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the full html from my index.cshtml file

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="formtextmatch">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea required id="text" name="text" 
                    class="form-control has-error" rows="5" 
                    placeholder="enter text to search for"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subtext" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subtext</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input required type="text" id="subtext" name="subtext" 
                    class="form-control" placeholder="enter subtext to search for" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
                <input type="button" id="GetCount" name="GetCount" 
                    value="Get Count" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="results" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                Subtext has been found at position
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <p class="form-control-static" id="results">
                    Click Get Count for results</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#formtextmatch").validate({
                rules: {
                    text: "required",
                    subtext: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    text: "Text is required",
                    subtext: "Subtext is required"
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter('.form-group');
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                }
            });
        });


        $("#GetCount").click(function() {
            toastr.options = {
                "debug": false,
                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                "onclick": null,
                "fadeIn": 300,
                "fadeOut": 1000,
                "timeOut": 5000,
                "extendedTimeOut": 1000
            };
            if (!$("#formtextmatch").valid()) {
                toastr.error("Ensure that the text and subtext values are supplied");
                return;
            }
            $.blockUI({
                message: '<p>Please wait</br>while query is being executed...</p>'
            });

            var textValue = $("#text").val();
            var subtextValue = $("#subtext").val();

            $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/findstrings/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: {
                        text: textValue,
                        subtext: subtextValue
                    }
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    if (data.length == 0)
                        $("#results").html("There is no output");
                    else
                        $("#results").text(data);
                })
                .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    toastr.error(textStatus);
                    toastr.error(errorThrown);
                })
                .always(function() {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    toastr.info('Search complete');
                });
        });

    </script>
}
```

With this code, the toastr is popping up, but the controls css is not being correctly set to indicate an error, or display the error message defined in the validation rule

Comment: maybe you have done this , did you check the javascript console ?

Comment: The current code that I am testing includes the required attribute, and when I step into the method I can get the alert to function, but the css on the elements does not change. Without the attribute, then nothing, the form is considered valid.

Comment: Removed the answer. Just for testing can you also try adding @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") into index.cshtml at the end. I remember I have seen trouble with validation when validation script are parsed before a partial view (which needs validation).

Comment: I moved the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") into the index.cshtml. Still did not resolve the problem. So I looked at the files installed in my scripts folder. jquery.validate.js, jquery.validate.min.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js. So as a test, I changed the bundle to remove the wildchar and link it directly to one of the files: jquery.validate.js and then the validation appeares to work.

Comment: Problem now is that both error messages are appearing after every div, instead of only being display after the correct control